# BUSCARX contra una tabla dinamica

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando buscar los valores de una columna de tipo General en la columna de una Tabla Dinámica también e tipo general con la función BUSCARX pero no me funciona
Si lo hago contra 2 columnas fuera de una tanbla dinámica funciona bien

[image: BUSCARX]

Pero si las matrices implicadas estan en una tabla dinámica

[image: BUSCARX2]

Donde si está el valor buscado

[image: BUSCARX3]

No me lo encuentra

Alguna idea?

Salu2

Comment: ¿Porqué no usas BUSCARV? De todas maneras, en tus ejemplo, en la celda A2 el número está a la derecha, así que entiendo que lo está reconociendo como número en vez de como texto, pero en la columna E todos los números están a la izquierda, así que está siendo reconocidos como textos. Eso hace que buscar falle. Tienen que tener el mismo formato

Answer (score 1):

Esto es porque estás buscando un valor numérico entre valores de texto.

Para convertir el valor numérico de `A2` en texto, podés usar

```
"" & A2
```